# Django query: Sort objects by the number of occurrences of a value?

Tags: django

I'm trying to use Django to return a list of objects with duplicate values, sorted from most-duplicated to least-duplicated.

For example, let's say I have the following model:

```py
class Person(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
```

I want to return a list of `Person`s, sorted from those with the most common `name` to those with the least common `name`.

I know that I can use `values` and `annotate` to create a sorted list of `name` values like this:

```py
Person.values('name').annotate(Count('id')).order_by('id__count')
```

But I don't want a list of `name`s; I want a list of `Person` objects. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [Subquery](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions):

```
with_this_name = Person.objects.filter(name=OuterRef('name')).values('id')

persons = Person.objects.annotate(
     with_the_same_name=Count(Subquery(with_this_name))
).order_by(
    '-with_the_same_same'
)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you give your Count field in annotate a name, you should be able to sort on it.

```
Person.values('name').annotate(duplicates=Count('id')).order_by('duplicates')
```

...or '-duplicates' if you want to sort descending.

Comment: Unfortunately, this still leaves me with a list of `name`s, not a list of `Person`s like I wanted.